# Where does Apple store Maps Guides data? Is there a way to back it up?

Tags: macos, icloud, maps

Does anyone know if there is a way to create a backup of one's Guides? Or, at the very least, where the Guides file/files are stored?

I've now had an update to iOS 15 and a test installation of macOS Monterey (12.1, no less) bork my list of Guides in Apple Maps. I was lucky enough that, both times, I was able to reconstruct them from a device that was offline but still had the guides cached.

I would like to upgrade to Monterey at some point, but I don't want to go through the pain of recreating my Guides again, one item at a time. I have several Guides, many of which have 50+ entries, so it would be a considerable pain to do this.

It occurred to me that Apple must be storing the data somewhere in iCloud in order to sync the Guides, but I can't find it. I've looked through `~/Library/Mobile Documents/`, but I don't see anything that fits the bill. I've also looked online to see if anyone has described where in iCloud the Guides / Maps data are saved to, and I've tried searching for developer documentation relating to a Guides API or explanation of the structure, but I haven't found anything relevant thus far…

Comment: Update: So, I installed Monterey 12.2, and I at least figured out what is going on (sort of). There are possibly 2 separate problems:

Comment: 1) All of the Guides and saved places that I've created with more recent iOS versions seem to sync fine, but some of the earliest places I ever saved will not disappear if I remove them from a Guide; they just immediately reappear. I found a workaround that usually worked to get rid of them, seemingly permanently, but I think something in the data structure changed over time and wasn't accounted for in subsequent versions.

Comment: 2) The way Dropped Pins are saved may be buggy. I was able to create newly problematic saved Dropped Pins in my Monterey installation. Not sure exactly what caused them to be/become problematic or not (some were fine).

Comment: None of what I discovered answers my original question, but I am now at least hopeful that subsequent OS upgrades on other devices won't kill the list yet another time…